# how to store the AWS S3 bucket image name in mongoDB database using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have stored the image in the AWS S3 bucket. now I need to store that image name in MongoDB. how to do that?

*s3.js*

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { S3 } = require("aws-sdk");
const uuid = require("uuid").v4;

exports.s3Uploadv2 = async (file) => {
  const s3 = new S3();

 const param = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: `uploads/${uuid()}`,
    Body: "file.buffer",
  };

  return await s3.upload(param).promise();
};
```

*POST method*

```
router.post("/admin/add_profile", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const send = new SomeModel({
      first_name: req.body.first_name,
      last_name: req.body.last_name,
      phone: req.body.phone,
      email: req.body.email,
      image:s3Uploadv2(req.files),
    });
    send.save();
    // await s3Uploadv2(req.files);
    return res.json({ 
    responseMessage: "Everything worked as expected",
  });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json(err.message);
  }  
});
```

*need to store the image name*
[image: I need to store that image name in mongoose]

*the image stored in the S3 bucket as an object*
[image]